# simple IOS code with OpenCV can run on simulator but fail at real device

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

I am a beginner for IOS and using OpenCV in IOS, I drag opencv2.framework into my project, as codes shown below:

```
#import "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#import "opencv2/highgui/ios.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage* a = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jay1.jpg"];

    cv::Mat b;
    UIImageToMat(a, b);
    cv::cvtColor(b, b, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    UIImage* c = MatToUIImage(b);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:c];

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!" message:@"Welcome to OpenCV" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

This code can run successfully on Simulator. While I run it on a real device, I got a error, and I can't get further details (while clicking this error message, no response).

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error:
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Xcode(8.3) and IOS(10.3) device are all the latest versions, and OpenCV version is 2.4.9. I had also drag some necessary frameworks such as:

```
QuartzCore.framework  
CoreVideo.framework  
CoreMedia.framework  
CoreImage.framework  
AVFoundation.framework   
AssetsLibrary.framework   
Accelerate.framework   
CoreGraphics.framework   
Foundation.framework   
UIKit.framework 
opencv2.framework
```

Could anybody tell me how to run these codes on my real device. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What's more, I have downloaded OpenCV 3.2.0 IOS pack in [opencv](http://opencv.org/releases.html). It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `opencv2.framework` was built with only x86 and x86-64 architectures. You need to either find one that includes armv7, armv7s (for 32-bit iPhones) and arm64 (for iphone 6 and later), or build one from source (see [instruction](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/da3/tutorial_ios_install.html)).

Comment: I will try this method, to build one that for arm64 and load into my project. Thank you.

Comment: OpenCV framework 3.2.0 for IOS  supports well. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, openCV can run on Real devices but failed to run on simulator. Can you help me how to run it on simulator?
Xcode Version 13.4